# Firestore "updateData" removes all the fields in document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my prpject I have a "employees" collection where every employee document containes fileds like: firstName, lastName, zipCode, refreshToken etc. 
When trying to update just a value of refreshToken i use 'updateData' like shown in documentation [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) 
my code:

```
    static func updateToken(token:String){

Firestore.firestore().collection("companies").document(self.user.companyId).collection("employees")
    .document(self.user.employeeId).updateData(["refreshToken" : token])
}
```

but that removees all other values of employee document (firstName, lastName, zipCode etc) and just new value of refreshToken exist in the node after operation. Am I doing something worng or I missunderstod idea of "updateData"?

Comment: Looks good to me. Are you sure you are not doing something else after updating? Also you can add the completion handler and print errors if any.

Comment: tryed restarting xcode/clean/rebuild  nothing helped so what I did I added to 'updateData' one more field so: updateData(["refreshToken" : token,"firstName":"John]) and that made it work without deleting other fields- still don't understand why but it works I guess:S (tryed error handler as well Vasil - no error came up there:s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to update the value of a field and if the document does exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided data, unless you specify that the data should be **merged** into the existing document, as follows:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("companies").document(self.user.companyId)
    .collection("employees").document(self.user.employeeId)
    .setData(["refreshToken" : token], merge: true)
}
```

See, I have used `setData()` function instead of `updateData()`.